# How to solve : internal_error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this problem. I run this code on flask api

```
# face verification with the VGGFace2 model
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
from keras_vggface.utils import preprocess_input
 
# extract a single face from a given photograph
def extract_face(filename, required_size=(254, 254)):
    # load image from file
    pixels = pyplot.imread(filename)

    # create the detector, using default weights
    detector = MTCNN()
    # detect faces in the image
    results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
    # extract the bounding box from the first face
    x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
    # extract the face
    face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    # resize pixels to the model size
    image = Image.fromarray(face)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    face_array = asarray(image)
    # print(face_array)
    return face_array

# extract faces and calculate face embeddings for a list of photo files
def get_embeddings(filenames):
    # extract faces
    faces = [extract_face(f) for f in filenames]
    # convert into an array of samples
    samples = asarray(faces, 'float32')
    # prepare the face for the model, e.g. center pixels
    samples = preprocess_input(samples, version=2)
    # create a vggface model
    model = VGGFace(model='vgg16', include_top=False, input_shape=(254, 254, 3), pooling='max')
    # perform prediction
    yhat = model.predict(samples)
    return yhat

# determine if a candidate face is a match for a known face
def is_match(known_embedding, candidate_embedding, thresh=0.45):
    # calculate distance between embeddings
    score = cosine(known_embedding, candidate_embedding)

    print('Match percentage (%.3f)' % (100 - (100 * score)))

    print('>face is a Match (%.3f <= %.3f)' % (score, thresh))

# define filenames
filenames = ['audacious.jpg', 'face-20190717050545949130_123.jpg']
# get embeddings file filenames
embeddings = get_embeddings(filenames)
# define sharon stone
sharon_id = embeddings[0]
# verify known photos of sharon
print('Positive Tests')
is_match(embeddings[0], embeddings[1])
```

I test with first hit, the process work well. But when the second hit that give error :

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
>
> 'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dty
> pe=float32) is not an element of this graph.'

If i run not on API, just in file then run with : python3 file.py, any times i run not give any errors
any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

`samples = asarray(faces, 'float32')`

and try to replace it with:

`samples = asarray(faces, dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: i have try this, but is not working. Still have the same error, any clue ?

Comment: yes, i have change to this :  samples = asarray(faces, dtype=np.float32), still on second i hit get same error

Comment: get_embeddings: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable